# Type hinting, union with forward references

Tags: python, python-3.5, type-hinting

Well in python 3 type hinting can now be used.

In my small script I wish to use type hinting. However a specific variable can be of two types. Either an `np.ndarray` (denoting a location), or an `CelestialBody` (from which to get the location).
The function is within a `CelestialOrbit` class.

Now the CelestialBody object isn't defined before the class so I'm using a forward reference, as described by the [pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)

```
from math import pi
import numpy as np
import math as m
from numpy import cos, sin, sqrt, power, square, arctan2, arccos, arcsin, arcsinh, radians, degrees
from scipy.optimize import *
import scipy as sp
import celestial_body as CB
import typing 

#....

def get_total_max_distance(self, ancestor_body: "CB.CelestialBody", eps=3*np.finfo(float).eps):
    if self.parent == ancestor_body:
        return self.apoapsis_distance
    orbit_list = list(self.create_tree_branch(ancestor_body))
    orbit_list.reverse()
    return orbit_list[0]._get_total_max_distance(ancestor_body.getGlobalPositionAtTime(),
                                                 ancestor_body.getGlobalPositionAtTime(),
                                                 orbit_list[1:], eps)
```

This works fine. Pycharm understands the type and it seems correct? Now I wish to change this so it understands it can take both a `CB.CelestialBody` and a `np.ndarray` type. (Where the second is already declared). I tried using a union according to the [pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types):

```
def get_total_max_distance(self, ancestor_body: typing.Union["CB.CelestialBody",np.ndarray], eps=3*np.finfo(float).eps):
```

However this fails with the remark: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CelestialBody'"

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paul/PycharmProjects/KSP_helper/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celestial_body import *
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\KSP_helper\celestial_body.py", line 7, in <module>
    import celestial_orbit as CO
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\KSP_helper\celestial_orbit.py", line 123, in <module>
    class CelestialOrbit:
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\KSP_helper\celestial_orbit.py", line 579, in CelestialOrbit
    def get_total_max_distance(self, ancestor_body: typing.Union["CB.CelestialBody",np.ndarray], eps=3*np.finfo(float).eps):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 537, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 494, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 494, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 185, in __subclasscheck__
    self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 172, in _eval_type
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CelestialBody'
```

How would I do this?

---

Following Kevin's advice show a bit easier error as one expect (cause, since the celestial_orbit module is imported by the celestial_body module the CelestialBody class hasn't be instantiated when python tries to instantiate the CelestialOrbit class).

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/Paul/PycharmProjects/KSP_helper/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Paul/PycharmProjects/KSP_helper/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from celestial_body import *
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\KSP_helper\celestial_body.py", line 7, in <module>
    import celestial_orbit as CO
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\KSP_helper\celestial_orbit.py", line 125, in <module>
    class CelestialOrbit:
  File "C:\Users\Paul\PycharmProjects\KSP_helper\celestial_orbit.py", line 581, in CelestialOrbit
    def get_total_max_distance(self, ancestor_body: typing.Union[CB.CelestialBody, np.ndarray], eps=3*np.finfo(float).eps):
AttributeError: module 'celestial_body' has no attribute 'CelestialBody'
```

---

The advice from Bakuriu - changing `CB.CelestialBody` to `celestial_body.CelestialBody` seems to work. However this is to me highly illogical - especially since the non-union version works with the `CB` alias.

Comment: Changing `CB.CelestialBody` to `celestial_body.CelestialBody` solves the problem? I initially posted this as an answer but checking the PEP PyCharm should actually be able to resolve `CB.CelestialBody`.  It may be PyCharm isn't implementing the PEP correctly in which case this is an answer and you should open a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker.

Comment: Anyway the error looks like a genuine one. I mean: it says `module object has no attribute` which means PyCharm is indeed evaluating `CB` as a module and looking for `CelestialBody`.  It sounds extremely fishy. Can you provide a minimal **complete** code that we can use to reproduce the error? Just copy those modules somewhere and start removing unneccessary code (e.g. all implementations of methods can be changed to `pass` or removed altogether) until you have found a minimal code that triggers this error.

Comment: That change (`CB.CelesticalBody` to `celestial_body.CelestialBody`) seems to fix it. But the error is reported by python.exe. Calling `python main.py` from shell results in the same error.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you do `"typing.Union[CB.CelestialBody,np.ndarray]"`. Disclaimer: I have never used type hints.

Comment: @Bakuriu: the reason your suggestion works is because `celestial_body` raises a `NameError` exception. This doesn't actually make the type definition *correct*; the name will *never* work in the context it is used. If PyCharm accepts this, then it is going above and beyond the specification.

Comment: Just a heads-up: the [bug I filed](http://bugs.python.org/issue26477) was marked as resolved; the fix will be part of 3.5.3 and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note*: This bug was recently fixed and will be part of Python 3.5.3. The answer below is outdated as of that version.

---

The forward reference fails to resolve because your `CB` module reference exists, but does not have a `CelestialBody` attribute, so an `AttributeError` exception is raised. Forward reference resolving (indirectly triggered by the `Union` type) allows for *`NameError` exceptions only*; supposedly because that's the canonical way to determine if a name is (not yet) available.

But given that the PEP provides you with an [example](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) where forward references are used to resolve a circular dependency between two modules (and thus you'd expect `AttributeErrors` to occur when prematurely referencing the name), I'm a little surprised that what you tried doesn't work, actually. You almost certainly have found a bug.

What happens is that the `Union[...]` type checks if the elements in the union are a subclass of another type in the union, and it is that check that triggers an attempt to look up the forward reference. If `'a.A'` and `'b.B'` (as in the circular reference example) are to work, the forward reference check should accept `AttributeError` as a valid exception to handle here. In fact, *any* exception should be swallowed at this point, because, as the PEP states:

> The string literal should contain a **valid Python expression** [...] and it should evaluate without errors **once the module has been fully loaded**.

Emphasis mine. When a `Union[..]` object is created, the module is not yet fully loaded, so given that any valid Python expression is permitted the code *should* treat *any* exception as indication the forward reference is not yet ready and ignore it.

The work-around would be for you to create function that turns the `AttributeError` into a `NameError`:

```
def _CelestialBody_forward_ref():
    try:
        return CB.CelestialBody
    except AttributeError:
        # not yet, raise NameError instead
        raise NameError('CelestialBody')
```

then use that in your forward references:

```
typing.Union['_CelestialBody_forward_ref()', np.ndarray]
```

This works because forward references are allowed to be any valid Python expression. Or you could make the whole `Union` declaration a string; it'll be evaluated later when all imports are done:

```
def get_total_max_distance(self, ancestor_body: "typing.Union[CB.CelestialBody,np.ndarray]", eps=3*np.finfo(float).eps):
```

I've [filed this as a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue26477) with the Python project.

---

As to why Bakuriu's suggestion of changing the expression to `celestial_body.CelestialBody`; that only 'works' because the name `celestial_body` raises a `NameError` exception. That name will *never* work in the context of your code, and thus the forward expression is not compliant with the PEP (it *won't* evaluate without errors once the module has been fully loaded).

If PyCharm accepts that reference anyway and correctly typechecks the function (e.g. it'll only let you use a numpy `ndarray` or `CelestialObject` instance when writing out a call), then that's due to PyCharm going beyond the specification here. Other tools are probably not going to be that forgiving.

In other words, as far as `typing` is concerned, you may as well have used `frobnar.FlubberdyFlub` as a forward reference there, it would have suppressed this specific bug just as much with the same effect; an invalid forward reference.

Comment: Thanks for elaborate reply. Using the workaround by changing the error type works, however it might also start confusing the IDE's. (and myself). Instead of reducing complexity through type-hinting it adds more complexity. I think I go for the "whole union string" - keeps the code at least easily readable.

Comment: @paul23: yes, the work-around is really just a technical demo to show that raising a `NameError` *does* work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that behaviour is that `CB.CelestialBody` does not throw a `NameError` since the global scope contains the name `CB`, but an `AttributeError` since the module does not have an attribute `CelestialBody`.

The `__subclasscheck__` from `typing.py` is

```
def __subclasscheck__(self, cls):
    if not self.__forward_evaluated__:
        globalns = self.__forward_frame__.f_globals
        localns = self.__forward_frame__.f_locals
        try:
            self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
        except NameError:
            return False  # Too early.
    return issubclass(cls, self.__forward_value__)
```

The `Union.__new__` tries to evaluate the type early as it is instantiated. However, `typing` does not expect an `AttributeError` be thrown. Indeed, after consulting [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references), it seems that this is an actual proposed use case for working about problems with circular imports; however the actual action is not properly handled by `Union`.

Anyhow, in your case if you do not actually need `celestial_body` in that module, except for type inferencing, you probably would not need to import that module at all, or import it at the end of the file, e.g.

```
def get_total_max_distance(self, ancestor_body: "CB.CelestialBody", eps=3*np.finfo(float).eps):
    ...

import celestial_body as CB
```

---

What comes to the non-`Union` version working without any problems - that is because the function annotations by *themselves* do not have any meaning to Python. The classes in `typing` themselves do care about what is given to them.

PyCharm on the other hand uses type inferencing that is independent of the `typing` module.